# Chat responses garble Unicode characters

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, unicode

When responding to a chat message by someone with non-ASCII Unicode characters in their name, I'm seeing the characters garbled in the response.

[image]

This is on Chrome 16.0.912.63 m (up-to-date non-beta version as of today) on Windows 7. People using other browsers reported that things were fine.

Comment: Which OS? I had problems with XP like this, but they've largely gone with Windows 7.

Comment: @Scrooge, this is Win7.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be working.  I'm able to tack some Chinese characters to the end of my user name, and then reply to myself in chat, and it seems to render just fine.  Of course, this is years later on Chrome 37+ and OSX, so I acknowledge this may have been a problem at one time.

[image]